# what does Makefile(90) : fatal error U1000 mean?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to do this from the command prompt:

```
C:/>nmake makefile
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Makefile(90) : fatal error U1000: syntax error : ')' missing in macro invocation
```

What does the number 90 refer to?

Any one can help?

If any one would like to see the Makefile it's here [Makefile](http://www.dive-in-essen.de/js/Makefile)

p.s: I use windows 7

Line 90 of the Makefile is:

```
LDSHARED = $(CC) -shared $(if $(filter-out -g -g0,$(debugflags)),,-s)
```

Comment: 90 is the line number. Is this double comma correct? `$(if $(filter-out -g -g0,$(debugflags)),,-s)`

Comment: Line 90 I would expect.

Comment: I deleted the c++ tag and added "make", since this isn't a C++ issue.  I also updated the question to show line 90 of the `Makefile`.

Answer (score 2):

90 is the line-number of the error. I suspect this makefile isn't meant to be used in `nmake`, since the syntax resembles `gnu-make` more than `nmake`.

You will probably have more luck if you run gnumake (`gmake` or possibly simply `make`).

Or, you could try to rewrite the makefile using the preprocessor macros, but it will require understanding what they are supposed to do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7y32zxwh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx